# "С Украины" или "из Украины"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Я знаю, что вопрос "в Украине" или "на Украине" тут уже [обсуждался](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/46568/%D0%9D%D0%B0-%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83). А вот как быть, когда наоборот: с Украины или из Украины?

Comment: @Aer Ну как может человек в 13-м году написать, что вопрос обсуждаЛся через два года в 15-м?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой наверно, вопрос, на который ссылался автор, был объединен с каким-то другим. Ничего страшного.

Comment: @Aer Он вроде не на что не ссылался, просто написал, что обсуждали это.

Answer (score 2):

Предлог "С" чаще используется в тех случаях, когда речь идет о территории (он обозначает направление  с поверхности предмета). Например, приехать с Поволжья,  с Урала. Предлог "ИЗ" чаще используется, когда речь идет о государстве (обозначает направление из предмета). Соответственно, предлог "С" как бы говорит о том, что Украина была частью Российского государства, а предлог "ИЗ" подчеркивает ее самостоятельность. Некоторые политологи, чтобы не обидеть украинских друзей, предлогом ИЗ пользуются преимущественно в гостях. Возможно, именно этот вариант будет признан основным - в принципе, он не противоречит грамматике русского языка (из Карелии, из Крыма).

Answer (score 1):

> Я знаю, что вопрос "в Украине" или "на Украине" тут уже обсуждался. А вот как быть, когда наоборот: с Украины или из Украины?

Когда "На" - тогда "С"
Когда "С" - тогда "НА".

Простите за самоцитирование, но

*Держусь я третий день без сна,

Стакан в себя залив.

Я только что вернулся с на...

И вот - послали в...*

*Судьба такая мне дана,

Вся жизнь - сплошной призыв.

Пошлют меня обратно в на...

Когда вернусь я из в...*

*Еще поллитру съев до дна,

Я вышел на карниз.

Мне цель отчетлива видна-

Теперь вперед и вниз...

Туда ведет дорога вна,

Оттуда едешь изс.*
(С) 2003 г.

Comment: Это что, стихи бегемотуса о самом себе?? Такой вид авторского флуда редко проникает на ресурс Хэшкод РЯ, может, и приживется))) Пишите еще, народ с удовольствием почитает про ваши откровенные экзерсисы... *Экзервнизы*, я хотел сказать.

Comment: Стих не лишён грубого юмора: в Интернете и не такое пишут!По-моему, @Дерзкий излишне придирчив. Хотя лично я не решился бы опубликовать подобный эксперимент... И всё-таки юмор налицо!

Answer (score 0):

Сначала надо определиться:"в Украине" или "на Украине". Предлогу С соответствует НА, а ИЗ - В. Материал 5 класса.