# Подарок из или Подарок с

Tags: орфография

Когда подарок привезли из какой-то страны, как правильно сказать?
Подарок из Танзании? Подарок из Кипра? Подарок из Маврикия? (т.е. он, подарок, приехал из)
или
Подарок с Танзании? Подарок с Кипра? Подарок с Маврикия? (т.е. подарок сам с Кипра)

Непонятно как раз в случае со странами мужского рода. Т.к. привык "с Урала" и "из Сибири".

Answer (score 1):

В Вашем случае речь идет о странах, поэтому:

**Подарок из Танзании, из Кипра, из Маврикия.**

Вот цитата из одного старого ответа (@София): 
См: ["С Украины" или "из Украины"?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/27794/%d0%a1-%d0%a3%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%a3%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b)

*Предлог "С" чаще используется в тех случаях, когда речь идет о территории (он обозначает направление с поверхности предмета). Например, приехать с Поволжья, с Урала. Предлог "ИЗ" чаще используется, когда речь идет о **государстве** (обозначает направление из предмета).*

Споры не утихают только по поводу Украины (с Украины или из Украины).